# Event handlers aren not attaching to select menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning javascript and jquery and I'm a bit stuck. For some reason the event handlers are not attaching correctly. I thought the .change() was the correct one to use for select menus.

```
         $('#tier1').change(function(){
            var tier1 = $('#tier1').find(":selected").text();
            if(tier1 != 'Month'){
                $('#tier2').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
         });
```

Comment: can you share the html as well

Answer (score 2):

You need to take of below things.

- Make Sure `jQuery` library is added into `head` tag,
- make sure you are wrapping your code into `$(document).ready(function() { //code });`
- Make Sure `ID` for each `DOM` are unique.
- Make Sure `DOM` is present which you are selecting using `jQuery selector`,

**Example**

```
<head>
   <script src="jQuery.js"></script>
   <Script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tier1').change(function(){
            var tier1 = $('#tier1').find(":selected").text();
            if(tier1 != 'Month'){
                $('#tier2').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
         });
     });
   </script>
</head>
<input id="tier1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I know, `.change()` **is** to be used with select menus... but I think there's something else amiss with your code. 
Instead of

```
var tier1 = $('#tier1').find(":selected").text();
```

try

```
var tier1 = $('#tier1').find(":selected").val();
```

If not, scatter some `console.log` around... Firefox's Firebugger and Chrome's Dev Tools should catch them and give you some clues as to what is happening.